# Visual Studio C++ program cannot find the include folder even when specified

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, header-files, include-path

I am just starting out in C/C++ programming using Visual Studio Code installed. I have all the necessary packages installed. My CPP project has the following directory structure:

```
DesignCPP #(parent/working directory)
/include
/mains
/source
```

The c_cpp_properties.json file has the following code:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "/home/pinaki/Finance_with_C++/DesignCPP/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"                
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Snippet of the C++ Program I am trying to run:

```
#include <Random1.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double SimpleMonteCarlo1(double Expiry,
                     double Strike,
                     double Spot,
                     double Vol,
                     double r,
                     unsigned long NumberOfPaths)
{
...
..
```

Ctrl+Shift+B returns:

```
> Executing task:  g++ -g mains/SimpleMCMain1.cpp -o SimpleMCMain1.out && clear && ./SimpleMCMain1.out <

mains/SimpleMCMain1.cpp:8:10: fatal error: Random1.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Random1.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

As you can see it is not able to locate the header files in the include directory which has been specified explicitly in the cpp_properties.json file.

I read a lot similar stack question question to figure out the problem without any success.

Please advice since I am struggling with it since yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you've written `#include <someFile.h>`. What you should've done is use `#include "someFile.h"`.

When using **<>** you tell the compiler to search its own directory for includes. When using **""** you are telling the compiler to search the specified include path.

Edited for clarity:
Simply specify the -I flag for gcc with your include folder.
For you it would be something like this `g++ -I include -g mains/SimpleMCMain1.cpp -o SimpleMCMain1.out && clear && ./SimpleMCMain1.out`

Comment: I did what you said but still getting the same error. Then I tried copying the Random1.h file to the mains directory where the cpp file resides. This then worked.

Now changing to #include <Random.h> gives me the same error even when it resides in directory of the cpp. So I am not able to follow the line of reasoning. Please elaborate and thanks for helping.